# Average sum in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have an object of massives - [image]

How to count an average sum of all rating properties

Answer (score 0):

```
$averageRating = UserRating::find()->where(['user_id'=>3])->average('rating');
```

ref - https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#average()-detail